# How can I swap a word in a group of words with a symbol ?

Tags: java, sdk

I have to swap every word containing the letter 'g' by # .

For example :

"I am sitting together with my friends" will become "I am # # with my friends"

"Together" and "sitting" will be swapped by #

What I've tried so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  java.lang.String s = "I am sitting together with my friends will become";
  java.lang.String sTemp[] = s.split(" ");
  for(int i=0;i<sTemp.length;i++)
  {
    if(sTemp[i].contains("g"))
    {
      sb.append("# ");
    } else
    { 
      sb.append(sTemp[i].toString()+" ");
    }
  } 
  System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        java.lang.String s = "I am sitting together with my friends will become";
        java.lang.String sTemp[] = s.split(" ");
   for(int i=0;i<sTemp.length;i++){
     if(sTemp[i].contains("g")){
          sb.append("# ");

      }else{
         sb.append(sTemp[i].toString()+" ");
     }
  }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static String swapWordsWithString (String inputString, String searchString, String swapString)
    //inputString == "I am sitting here together with my friends"
    //searchString == "g"
    //swapString == "#"
    String output = "";
    String[] words = inputString.split(" ");
    for(String x : words)
        if(x.contains(searchString))
            output = output + swapSring + " ";
        else
            output = output + x + " ";
    return output.trim();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it shows string.String does not hav a main method , Any idea to solve it

Comment: Nice to hear :) you can place this code in a static method which receives `myString` as argument and returns `output` at the end. Then you could call that from your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can first split your `String` into a `String[]` by spaces. Then iterate over this array and replace each word containing a 'g' with a '#'. After that `cocatenate` a new `String` with the values of the replaced array and you'r done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String s = "I am sitting together with my friends will become";
       String sTemp[] = s.split(" ");
   for(int i=0;i<sTemp.length;i++){
     if(sTemp[i].contains("g")){
          sb.append("# ");

      }else{
         sb.append(sTemp[i].toString()+" ");
     }
  }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of ***StringBuilder*** is recommended.

```
String[] s = "I am sitting together with my friends".split(" ");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].indexOf('g') != -1) {
        s[i] = "#";
    }
    sb.append(s[i]).append(' ');
}

System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1));
```

If you already have ***Apache Commons*** Lang in your classpath *(it becomes even easier)*

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].indexOf('g') != -1) {
        s[i] = "#";
    }
}

// Using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
System.out.println(StringUtils.join (s, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String inputString = "I am sitting together with my friends";
 String outputString = "";

 for( String value : inputString.split(" ")) {
     if(value.contains("g")) {
         outputString += " #";
     } else {
         outputString += " "+ value;
     }
 }  
 System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "I am sitting together with my friends";

    String[] temp = s.split(" ");

    for(int a=0; a<temp.length; a++)
    {
        if(temp[a].contains("g"))
        {
            s = s.replace(temp[a], "#");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```